# Redirect User to their Profile Page After Saving

Tags: users, nodes

Each user has a "Edit" tab/button on their profile. They click it, edit their profile, and when it is saved, they are kept on that page. I want the user to be taken back to his/her "View" or profile page.

Comment: using rules module consider an option for you?

Comment: Related with answers for D8: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131324/redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-user-update-their-profile/131338

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @[Aboodred](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7733/aboodred1), if you already have the Rules module installed, adding a simple rule can do the job.

1. Create a rule with the React on event type `After updating an existing user account`.
2. Add a `Page redirect` action. Set the 'Data selector' field to `account:url` (either manually or using the dropdown).

[image]

Comment: This worked @obliquely! Many thanks (and to @Aboodred1 too).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with code instead of rules you can take a look at how the `user_edit_cancel_submit` function does it in user.pages.inc.

First you define an submit function:
`$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_redirect_after_save';`

Then you add the function:

```
function custom_redirect_after_save($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
    unset($_GET['destination']);
  }
  $form_state['redirect'] = array("user", array());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8/9:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Redirect users to their profile pages.
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_user_edit_form_submit';
}

/**
 * Redirect users to their profile pages when submitting the edit form.
 */
function MYMODULE_user_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.user.canonical', ['user' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional submit function to `user_profile_form` by using `hook_form_alter` to return back to profile page after editing user profile.

Your code should look like the following:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MODULE_NAME_user_profile_form_submit';
}

function MODULE_NAME_user_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do a drupal_goto because you can use a $form_state['redirect'] instead. See the answer from @andeersg.

Comment: @JenLampton all roads lead to Rome :D

Comment: @Aboodred1If you use `drupal_goto` you cut off every other submit function or alter hooks. If you set the redirect key in the form_state all the submit functions will execute before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Drupal 6) it was

1) Install Rules Module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/rules

2) Activate Rules Module in Administration Console

[site url]/admin/build/modules (Look for a new Module category called Rules)

3) Enable the following Module(s):

Rules Administration UI 6.x-1.5 Provides the administration UI for rules.
Depends on: Rules (enabled)

Rules Forms support 6.x-1.5 Provides events, conditions and actions for rule-based form customization.
Depends on: Rules (enabled)

Rules Scheduler 6.x-1.5 Schedule the execution of rule sets.
Depends on: Rules (enabled)

4) Navigate to Rules area and configure the rule:

Rules | Triggered Rules | Add a new rule

....fill in as per Obliquely's instructions...

BUT - There was no DATA SELECTOR or dropdown.

Instead I had to fill it in by hand, which was easy:

To:  [account:account-url]

Answer (score -1):

It worked in Drupal 8

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

function YOUR_MODULE_user_update($account) {
  $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $url = '/u/' . $uid;
  $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $request->getSession()->save();
  $response->prepare($request);
  \Drupal::service('kernel')->terminate($request, $response);
  $response->send();
}
```

Comment: This is a bad answer because terminating the kernel early while in a hook means that no other hook will get a chance to operation.