# Redirect to a specific page when user update their profile

Tags: users, forms

Is there any way to redirect the user after save their profile information.

I would like to redirect them to a specific page.

To be clear, here is the Flow:

1. User go in his profile
2. He change his password information
3. The user click on Save Button
4. The information is save and I want to redirect him on a specific page (node/xxx)

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64171/redirect-user-to-their-profile-page-after-saving

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code for Drupal 8 :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'user_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_mymodule_user_edit_form_submit';
  } 
} 
function _mymodule_user_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.user.canonical', ['user' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id()]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom submit handler to the user edit form and then do the redirect there:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_function';
  }
}

function custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('node/xxx');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by rule , create a rule then redirect to a url after user update 
I create it for you, just change the url and import it

Go to `admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/import` and 
import this url ( first change the url , I set it to jean-fransico :) )

```
{ "rules_redirect_after_user_update" : {
    "LABEL" : "redirect after user update",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "Jean-Francois" } } ]
  }
}
```